# Most of my Facebook Likes have disappeared from my website

Tags: facebook, like

Until two days ago, I had 417 Facebook Likes on my website http://www.ridiculouslife.net/
Now i have just 33. 
Even when I input my url into the Facebook developers Get the Like Button [generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) it still comes up as 33.
Does anyone know what happened and how I may fix it?
Thanks
A

Answer (score 1):

you have the like button for the site `ocdridiculouslife.com` 
Was the like button initially for `ridiculouslife.net` ? 
In the mean time did you change the URL for the like button or did any kind of redirects ?
[Try this](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
to know the issues in  your site.

Comment: Yes the site was originally `ocdridiculouslife.com`. I changed the URL to `ridiculouslife.net` quite a few months ago and have had no problems. Now, even when I input `ocdridiculouslife.com` into the Facebook developers Get the Like Button generator it still comes up as 33.

Comment: Oh yes, and I tried the Debugger and got this warning: Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property:The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.      I have no clue what to do about this. All help is welcome, as I really have no clue what I am doing. Thanks so much. xxx

Answer (score 0):

Did you purchase Facebook Likes for your website? Generally it happens in the case of Fake likes.